# How to set up a minimal, safe cloud architecture? (database + files + application)

Tags: mysql, cloud, qt5

I'm developing business administration software. The aim is to make it as flexible and portable as possible.
The main application can be executed on many platforms (mobile/desktop).

I'll offer a cloud service to access files & database, anytime, anywhere.

Now I'm not sure about safety.
For the file:

- **Can a HTTP-connection provide sufficient safety? (its very sensitive
  data!)**
- **Or should I consider HTTPS?**

For the database:

- **Is a basic connection in Qt5 with an online MySQL5-database safe?**

I have a background in business, user experience and programming, but need your advice to get my further development on the right track. Safety before anything, my customers should get a solid product.

Thanks in advance.

A simple scheme can be found at:https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9o0u.jpg

Comment: Absolute security is afforded by understanding all risks every single step, every single line of code on the way. To be honest, if you have to ask whether HTTP is safe enough, I don't think you have enough background to keep this up all the way through production to not introduce some backdoor somewhere; even if we answered your two questions here. If this is really sensitive and important, you should probably hire an expert.

Comment: I pretty much agree with @deceze, but only wish to add that security is relative - there's no such thing as "absolute security".  Not only must one understand every single line of code, but also every single API and system call, every single referenced library, every piece of software and hardware involved, every network interface and connection... and only then after one has identified the threat: who might try to attack the system; what capabilities they have; how much resource they are able to devote; what you consider to be a failure...

Comment: One only needs to read recent news to appreciate that if you're trying to protect your system against motivated State actors (three letter agencies etc), you may as well give up now.  They can just visit your hosting provider and tamper with your hardware (perhaps with a secret court warrant, or perhaps through more dubious means), or engineer a situation by which you accidentally introduce some malicious code, or simply arrest you and force you to hand over your credentials... in short, your question is far too vague to advise on what is necessary to "secure" your system.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I didn't want to overkill, but since things can't be killed at all I'll invest in further studies and consult a security expert. 
Still I think asking for the state of Qt5-libraries to provide decent security isn't amazingly vague. I need some base to rely on, or I'll spend a lifetime on learning befor publishing anything.

Comment: It all depends on what *you* mean by "decent security", which would mean different things to different people depending on their threat model.

Comment: Are you sure you want to develop your own? There are many existing solutions out there. Qt Cloud Services, for example, is designed for cross-platform Qt apps: http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Cloud-Services/ It is developed by Digia themselves, and has tight integration with Qt.